# Maclaurin series finding pattern

Tags: calculus

Find Maclaurin series for $f(x) = \frac{2}{(1+x)^3}$

$$f(x)=2(1+x)^{-3}, f(0)=2$$
$$f'(x)=-6(1+x)^{-4}, f'(0)=-6$$
$$f''(x)=24(1+x)^{-5}, f''(0)=24$$
$$f'''(x)=-120(1+x)^{-6}, f'''(0)=-120$$
$$f^4(x)=720(1+x)^{-7}, f^4(0)=720$$
$$2-6x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-120\frac{x^3}{3!}+720\frac{x^4}{4!}+...$$

I'm trying to put the expanded form in sigma notation and the below is what I tried

$$2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(n+2)x^n}{n!}$$$$2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(n+2)x^n}{n!}=2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n(n+2)(n+1)x^n$$

The solution was $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+2)(n+1)x^n$

What happened to the 2 or are my steps wrong?

Comment: All with same  exponent $-3$?

Comment: it's a typo, will fix it.

Comment: $2=(-1)^0(0+2)(0+1)x^0$? SO the solution is correct. Just re-index your series

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function

$g(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)}$

Notice that $g''(x)=f(x)$

But also notice that the power series of $g(x)$ for $|x|<1$ is just the geometric series given by

$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n$

Differentiating twice yields

$f(x)=g''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^nn(n-1)x^{n-2}$

Shifting indicies gives

$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(n+1)(n+2)x^{n}$

Which is exactly what you want.

Strictly speaking, the differentiation performed above relies on uniform convergence of the power series on all compact subintervals of $(-1,1)$ if we're being strictly rigorous.

Comment: I did it first by differentiating but never incremented the index and had n= 0, instead of n = 2. Do you increment the index every time you differentiate, and subtract when integrating?

Comment: Well notice that there's actually no index shift after differentiating. The first two terms will be zero because of the product n(n-1) in the series. So the sum from 0 to infinity would be the same as the sum from 2 to infinity.

Comment: I get the same answer by incrementing the index when differentiating. Finally, just like you did subtract 2 from the index and add to the other n's. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it.